# last point also rendering for actor in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am new to lib gdx and facing problem of proper rendering. While I am moving Actor , it is moving fine but last position frame is not cleared from screen , so whole path is appearing while moving .

It is like if object 1 move then it appear like 11111111111111111111111111111 while it should be only at last point like                      1.

My actor

public class SinglePipe extends Actor {

```
@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.setColor(getColor().r, getColor().g, getColor().b, getColor().a);
    batch.draw(Assets.car, this.getX(), this.getY());

}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.act(delta);

}
```

}

Screen class

public class GameScreen implements Screen, GestureListener {

```
private Stage stage;
private SinglePipe singlePipe;

Logger logger = new Logger("");

public GameScreen() {
    // Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
    logger.setLevel(5);
    stage = new Stage();
    singlePipe = new SinglePipe();
    stage.addActor(singlePipe);

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // camera.update();
    handleInput();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_GREEN_BITS);
    stage.act();
//  stage.draw();

}

private void handleInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
        // singlePipe.addAction(Actions.moveBy(5, 5));
        // singlePipe.addAction(Actions.rotateBy(180));
        singlePipe.setX(singlePipe.getX() + 5);
        singlePipe.setY(singlePipe.getY() + 5);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your render method use:

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`
```